# SQL Group by Sales Rep - Select 2 counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query a table that has leads assigned by sales rep to return the unique number of leads grouped by agent and also the number sold.  There can be multiple leads from one buyer, I would like to select distinct so each buyer is counted only once.  Here is the layout of the data:

| AgentId | BuyerEmail | Product | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lisa@gmail.com | Jeans | 1 |
| 1 | lisa@gmail.com | Hat | 1 |
| 1 | ryan@gmail.com | Shoes | 3 |
| 2 | mark@gmail.com | Jeans | 1 |
| 2 | mark@gmail.com | Socks | 1 |
| 2 | mark@gmail.com | Hat | 1 |
| 4 | john@gmail.com | Shirt | 3 |
| 5 | lou@gmail.com | Hat | 3 |
| 5 | tim@gmail.com | Shirt | 3 |

I would like to return a dataset like the following:

| AgentId | UniqueLeads | QtySold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

I can query this individually but I can't get it to return in one result set.  Here are the 2 separate queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT BuyerEmail) FROM SalesLeads GROUP BY InitialAgent 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT BuyerEmail) FROM SalesLeads WHERE Category = 3 GROUP BY InitialAgent
```

How can I query the table and have both data points return in one result set? Please note, a category = 3 means it is sold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to calculate QtySold in the same statement:

```
select AgentId, 
    count(distinct BuyerEmail) as UniqueLeads, 
    count(case when Category = 3 then Category end) as QtySold
from SalesLeads
group by AgentId
```

When Category is anything other than 3 the case statement returns null so that record isn't counted in the QtySold calculation.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=939e3b9cedca612384e0b3ea8029b432)

Comment: `case when Category = 3 then 1 end` would be better, as you are counting rows, not categories